# change the registry in the docker https://index.docker.io/v1/ to V2

Tags: docker, artifactory

Installed Docker version 19.03.12 on ubuntu . using the command docker info

it is showing registry as like below

Registry:https://index.docker.io/v1

Can anyone suggest a method to change the registry to v2 (https://index.docker.io/v2)

There is an issue to pull the image from the docker artifactory repository v2

Answer (score 2):

Vasanthan, if you have just installed docker and all the docker images will be resolved through docker hub, you can set up the same environment in Artifactory by using the default docker remote repository as below,
[image: Docker remote repository hitting the docker hub]

As you can observe that it is by default v2 and hitting the "https://registry-1.docker.io/" which hits the docker hub. There is no need to use the "https://index.docker.io/v2 " instead use the "https://registry-1.docker.io/". I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how i change the  registry as "https://registry-1.docker.io/"

Comment: How exactly you are using Artifactory as a docker registry? You can simply create a docker remote repository which will already be pointing to "https://registry-1.docker.io/" and you can set this docker remote repository as the docker registry in your docker client and try to fetch any image which is available in docker hub

Comment: Thanks.How to set  this docker remote repository as the docker registry in my docker client

Comment: There are 2 ways to set up Artifactory as docker registry,
1. Using the reverse proxy and either subdomain/port method
2. Without reverse proxy and using the repository path method.
Please refer to this wiki https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Docker+Registry for more information on setting up.